# Why TypeError from nextElementSibling.tagName?

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I has been the TypeError as `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'value.querySelector('h1').nextElementSibling.tagName')`. So it's  be error, when executed compile on the browser without `&& value.querySelectorAll('hr')[0]`. In other word, it isn't be error, when executed compile within the `&& value.querySelectorAll('hr')[0]`. In conclusion, why TypeError, when executed compile on the browser without `&& value.querySelectorAll('hr')[0]`?

```js
      let countOfSetId = 0;
            
      function nav() {
        for (let value of document.querySelectorAll('#article ol li')) {
          console.log(value);
            
          if (value.id == false
              && value.querySelector('h1')
              && value.querySelector('hr') // TypeError, when toggle comment this line.
              && value.querySelector('h1').nextElementSibling.tagName == 'HR') {
            
              console.log(1);
              value.setAttribute('id', 'li-' + countOfSetId);
            
              countOfSetId++;
            
            } else {
                      console.log(0);
                   }
          }
    }
```

```html
   <article id="article">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <h1>New list of article(none-id).</h1>
                    <h2>second</h2>
                    <hr>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>New list of article(none-id).</h1>
                </li>
                <li id="li-1">
                    <h1>Navigation to content of article.</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <ol>
                        <li id="">
                            <h1>Navigation to content of article 1-2</h1>
                            <hr>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>New list of article(none-id).</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <p>hello</p>
                </li>
                <li id="li-2">
                    <h1>Navigation to content of article 2</h1>
                    <hr>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </article>
```

Comment: not able to replicate.Please create working demo

Comment: WHY are you using querySelectorAll when you are selecting the first  index?? Jut use querySelector like you do on the third line...

Comment: There is no next sibling, so nextElementSibling is `null`, and `null` has no properties (like `tagName`). Trying to access a property on `null` (or `undefined`) is a TypeError.

Comment: @brk What you’re mean? Are you want an console log?

Comment: @skyline3000 I know, it isn’t object. But I was want question to you about “Why is ‘nextElementSibling’ not ‘TypeError’ when value.querySelector(“hr”) is enabled?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part.

```
<li>
   <h1>New list of article(none-id).</h1>
</li>
```

There's no `nextElementSibling` of h1 here.
So `nextElementSibling.tagName` throws an error.

Comment: Why is ‘nextElementSibling’ not ‘TypeError’ when value.querySelector(“hr”) is enabled?

Comment: @suk9206 Cuz it confirms that hr(which is nextElementSibling if h1) is present.